# Comment traduire cette instance de « which » ?

Tags: conjonctions, pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées

On sait que *which* peut être traduit par « laquelle » et ses variantes quand c'est un pronom relatif. Je voudrais savoir comment traduire *which* dans une phrase comme celle-ci:

> I asked him, **which** was a bad idea.

Je ne crois pas qu'on peut utiliser *lequel* or *laquelle* parce qu'ici, *which* ne répresente pas une chose definie.

Est-ce que « ce qui » suffit ici?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

« Ce qui » se traduit bien par *which* dans cette phrase :

> Je lui ai demandé, ce qui était une mauvaise idée.

Comment: Pouvez-vous citer un référence sur le web ou ailleurs svp? merci.

Answer (score 1):

Pronoms relatifs composés (such as *lequel*, *laquelle* and so on) can more accurately be translated to 'which one(s)'.

The sentence that you have mentioned can be taken in two meanings. If you are trying to say that I asked him which (one) (of many different ideas) was a bad idea, then you would use a pronom relatif composé which in this case would be *laquelle* (as you are replacing the noun 'idée').

However, if you mean to say that asking him was a bad idea, then you would use a pronom relatif indéfini which in this case would be *ce qui*.

Remember, there are three different types of pronoms relatifs:

- Pronoms relatifs simples - *qui*, *que*, *où*, *dont*
- Pronoms relatifs composés - *lequel*, *laquelle*, *lesquels*, *lesquelles*
- Pronoms relatifs indéfinis - *ce qui*, *ce que*, *ce dont*, *quoi*

Most of the above mentioned relative pronouns (with the exceptions of *où*, *dont* and *ce dont*) roughly translate to *which* in English. 
Depending on the context, you must decide which pronom relatif to use. It may be difficult at first (it still is for me), but as the French say: C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron.

Comment: The comma located between **him** and **which** is breaking the sentence in two parts so rules out your first alternative (*laquelle*).

Answer (score 0):

You could also translate this sentence by :

> Je lui ai demandé, c'était une mauvaise idée.